# Call script from Server side in asp.net mvc core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm trying to open bootstrap modal from server side in asp.net mvc core 3.0 but unable open getting error

```
ViewBag.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "$('#modalRegisterForm').modal('show')", true);
```

[image: Error Screen Shot]

Comment: ViewBag does not contain such method,so you could see a runtime error instead of build time error.

Comment: But how to call client side script from server side mvc C#?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a variable in my PageModel:

```
public string errMsg { get; private set; }
```

And then using this variable in the cshtml page in a script section:

```
<script>
  if ('' !== '@Model.errMsg') {
    window.alert('@Model.errMsg');
  }
</script>
```

So, by assigning a value to my errMsg variable in the code-behind I can control the rendering of scripts client side based on what's going on server side. I think you can get what you want with the modal using this approach?